# How to convert an image to a polygon-mesh 3d model using python

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network, 3d

I am working on a project that requires real-time conversion of **images and videos to a 3d model** using deep learning . Although I have found ways to get a voxel model, I feel **polygon meshes** give finer models. Is there any way I can do this using python's libraries . I would love to know about any **previous works** on this topic.